# cd-ing to a directory with a lot of spaces--mac terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, cd, space

I want to cd to a path with spaces in the folder names, but it doesn't work. I want to navigate straight to a directory which has multiple levels of directories on the way, each with a lot of spaces. Please look at the following example:

Say I want to navigate to:

> ./Folder/Animal Pictures/Dog Pictures/Golden Retriever Pictures/Golden Retrievers Playing Ball

I tried:

```
cd ./Folder/"Animal Pictures"/"Dog Pictures"/"Golden Retriever Pictures"/"Golden Retrievers Playing Ball"
```

But I got the error:

```
cd: too many arguments
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your example looks fine syntax-wise – is this literally copied from the terminal (where you got the error message) or did you re-type it?

Comment: @user1686 - indeed, the quotes ought to work. I'd wondered if there were too many levels, but I've tested up to 5 deep, still works. The `./folder/` bothers me a bit. My answer below bypasses all the need for this, though, by simply dragging the required folder from Finder. This will make it apparent how terminal likes to see any particular path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments everyone! It wasn't copied from the terminal, I made up an example cuz the relevant folder names had a lot of personal info in it. I thought it was syntaxwise correct too, still no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Also I didn't know you could drag the folder into terminal, it's a great tip! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You use a backslash to indicate the next character is part of the name & not a split where a new instruction starts.

```
cd ./Folder/Animal\ Pictures/Dog\ Pictures/Golden\ Retriever Pictures/Golden\ Retrievers\ Playing\ Ball
```

You can test this - or even use it to be much quicker than typing, by just typing `cd`  then dragging the folder itself from Finder to Terminal. It will format it correctly for you.

Comment: Ahh the backslash worked! When I first read about the backslash I just assumed it treats EVERYTHING that comes after it as a string, but I guess the regular slash kind of resets it? Anyways the folder drag is also a great idea. Thanks a lot!